# VBA to Open Excel File and Paste Sheet 1 Data into “Main” Sheet in Current Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Ok so I have a current workbook (Original Workbook) with one Sheet.

I would like to open an existing workbook (Data Workbook) and copy all of the contents in Sheet 1 of 'Data Workbook', then paste everything into Sheet "Main" of 'Original Workbook'.

At the end of this process I would like to close the 'Data Workbook' So far I have the following code.

however it gives me an error message

> "Run-time error'1004':  Cannot paste that macro formula onto a worksheet":

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Main!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"

Exit Sub
Else
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
Next Sheet
End If
wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello please refer the code below and make changes according to your need. It does what you need.

```
Option Explicit
Sub import()
Dim filename As String
Dim curfilename As String

curfilename = ThisWorkbook.Name

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename)

With Sheets("1")
x.Sheets("1").Range("A1:Z10000").Copy   '/Provide the range
End With

Dim y As Workbook
Set y = Workbooks(curfilename)

With Sheets("Main")
y.Sheets("Main").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

x.Close SaveChanges:=False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend turning DisplayAlerts off without turning them back on at the end of your code.  Turn them off to suppress a specific alert and then turn it back on so it works when the user is not running your macro.

Comment: It is turned on when the code completes execution by default since 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' also turns back on automatically.